# Birt: Store user stay time on reports and visit counts to database

Tags: mysql, session, tomcat7, birt

I have deployed birtviewer on tomcat 7. I am using tomcat form based authentication to control users access to the reports. Currently I have come up with a requirement to store to mysql database the user visits counts and the time he spends on each birt report

I have done seme research on how to extract total session time from session variable but the problems I am facing are below

1) A session starts as soon as a user logs in. How do I collect the session info for the subsequent reports? For example I  have some bunch of reports that are connected to a main report. If a user logs in, he is taken to the main page. After that, the user is not required to log in to the next reports that  user visits. If the user visits other reports, how do I collect the information about the time that user spends on each report?

2) I would also like to collect the visit counts that a user makes to each report? How can I collect this info?

3) How can I send this info from birt reports to the database?

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more explanation. I have googled and could gather information about how to extract info from session variable but I could get any info on how to do it for each birt report separately (even though all the reports user the same session info)

Regards
Arif

Comment: I have some simular goals see [this on BIRT Exchange](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28375-can-i-use-cookies-to-recall-user-selected-parameters-from-last-visit/)  I have been side tracked by other priorities, but it does provide some ground work.  If you get a functioning system please post an answer here, I will be watching your question.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a [ServletFiler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) in Java and add the packed jar to the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your BIRT Viewer and configure the Filter mapping in the `WEB-INF\web.xml` of your viewer, so it is triggered every time you call an URL of the BIRT Viewer.

Insider your filter you can read the session time and save the timestamp and a click counter to your database. You can calculate the visited time by substracting it from the next saved timestamp identified by the session ID.